# How to count number of rows containing a value in current query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 With this table :
[image]

and i have the following query :

```
SELECT caller, called, SUM(duration) as duration, 
      dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, time))as Batch2 ,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch  
FROM  Calls oc
WHERE caller='somevalue'
GROUP BY called, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, time)),
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4),
          caller
ORDER BY duration DESC,called
```

Now i want to order the query by the amount of rows in the query that contain the same called value, meaning first results will be the called that appeared in most days.

Now the closest i got was using :

```
order by (select count(called) from Calls where called=oc.called ),
         duration DESC,
         called
```

But this returns all the appearnces of called in general and not grouped by as my initial query distincts values.

And i can't use `OVER()` as that will just return the number of rows in general.

This is an example of the output i have for now :

```
callervalue   somecalledvalue   589 2012-11-21 00:00:00.000 21.11.12
callervalue   somecalledvalue   551 2012-11-20 00:00:00.000 20.11.12
callervalue   somecalledvalue   506 2012-11-22 00:00:00.000 22.11.12
```

How can i achive this?

Comment: Not having your table structures, nor your data, I'm unable to run your queries. Could you give an example of what the output is from the first query, and how you'd *like* the output to be? (Or if you're feeling really nice, the above, plus table structures and sample data that matches them)

Comment: Damien i edited the question and Kuya, what do you mean?

Comment: what will be your final output?

Comment: The best you could simply create, insert your table schema, data in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/) makes easy for both parties and along the way you might find your answer yourself. ;-)

Comment: @KuyaJohn my output will be order by number of appearnces of every `called` column in a day

Comment: try `COUNT(called) OVER (PARTITION BY called)`

Comment: @ChrisBednarski I think this solves it, not sure as it's alot of data that i don't know. submit as answer and i'll mark it. Thanks m8!

Comment: @eric.itzhak yep, i just deleted the answer :D

Comment: why Over doesn't work? have you tried count(*) over (partition by called)?

Comment: @RomanPekar Yes roman Chris here made me realize that it does the trick and the problem is solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was posted by Chris Bednarski as a comment :

> try COUNT(called) OVER (PARTITION BY called)

Which did the trick.